# How to invoke injected bean methods from instance initializer block

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring and SpringMvc and I want to invoke a method of a service in some controller, and both them
are managed by Spring. When I try to do this I got NullPointerException, but I find that the Service's constructor truly called before I invoke this method.
I think maybe this Service has been added in Spring, but the property here in this controller has not be set.

How can I get it from SpringContext?

My code like this:

```
 @Controller 
 @RequestMapping("/test") 
 public class SomeController {

     @Resource
     private SomeService someService;

     {
         someService.serviceMethod();
         //And something more
     }

     @RequestMapping("/someMethod")
     private void controllerMethod(){

     } 
}
```

Comment: try this: add a property:
@Autowired SomeService someService;

in controllerMethod: someService.serviceMethod()

Comment: I know that it will work if I put "someService.serviceMethod();" in controllerMethod . but I want these code only run once instead of running every time when I call the method of this controller. @Si mo

Comment: try the @PostConstruct annotation? http://www.journaldev.com/2637/spring-bean-life-cycle-methods-initializingbean-disposablebean-postconstruct-predestroy-aware-interfaces

Comment: Thank you! Nice solution @Simo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call spring-injected service from an initializer block. The resource you annotated with @Resource has not been injected into the controller by spring yet! That's why you are getting the NullPointerException
Create a separate function annotated with @PostConstruct instead.

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/test") 
public class SomeController {

    @Resource
    private SomeService someService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(){
        someService.serviceMethod();
    }
}
```

That "postConstruct" method will be invoked after the bean (i.e. the controller) has been created and all the dependencies (including SomeService) has been injected into the bean. Of course, it satisfies your requirement that it should only be called once.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I want exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Your specific problem has to do with the way Java handles [Instance Initalizer Blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html):

> The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor. Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between multiple constructors.

If you want to stick with the initializer block you can solve the problem by adding a constructor to your controller and inject your service into it:

```
@Autowired
public SomeController(SomeService someService) {
  this.someService = someService;
}
```

**Alternatively**, your could remove the initializer block and add a [@PostConstruct](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html) annotated setup method.

```
@PostConstruct
public void setupSomeController(){
    someService.serviceMethod();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your perfect answer!